# Issue in opening Facebook page via Facebook Application instead of Browser

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, uri, android-facebook

I need to open Facebook page in my installed Facebook Application. I have called the below function for that :

```
private void loadFacebookUrl() {
    if (Constant.isOnline(AboutActivity.this)) {
        try {
            if (appInstalledOrNot(AboutActivity.this, "com.facebook.katana")) {
                this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/MyPage/")).setPackage("com.facebook.katana"));
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Constant.displayToast(AboutActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_internet));
    }
}
```

But, I am getting the following exception in my Logcat:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.facebook.com/... pkg=com.facebook.katana }
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3978)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3939)
07-07 14:19:24.070 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
07-07 14:19:24.071 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4262)
07-07 14:19:24.071 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4230)
07-07 14:19:24.071 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at com.app.thelist.activity.AboutActivity.loadFacebookUrl(AboutActivity.java:98)
07-07 14:19:24.071 5094-5094/com.app.thelist W/System.err:     at com.app.thelist.activity.AboutActivity.onClick(AboutActivity.java:76)
```

What should I have to do to get the task done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in the link format... you should use: **fb://facewebmodal/f?href=**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/mypage"));
```

check if he has the app, then use the above url format, else redirect him to the browser:

```
String pageurl = "https://www.facebook.com/mypage";
boolean hasFacebook = appInstalledOrNot(AboutActivity.this, "com.facebook.katana");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse((hasFacebook?("fb://facewebmodal/f?href="):"") + pageurl));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It works but not when the app is disabled, any idea?

Comment: the above code checks if the user has the app, then it sends your page url to the fb app.
if it's not available, then it will send the url to the web browser.